# Strange exception thrown when defining an expression with == between a generic struct type to its nullable counterpart

Tags: c#, generics, struct, nullable

**Final update:** See this [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16797890/why-are-generic-and-non-generic-structs-treated-differently-when-building-expres) that narrows the problem down to generic structs.

---

I have some code that is building an `Expression<Func<..>>` that compares a value type to the nullable of the same value type. In the line that defines the expression, I'm getting the following `InvalidOperationException`:

> The operands for operator 'Equal' do not match the parameters of method 'op_Equality'.

Any explanation for this?

**Note**: None of the overriden methods are ever called, the exception is thrown when the expression is being built by .NET

Here's the full code to reproduce the exception:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Linq.Expressions;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    struct MyStruct<T> : IEquatable<MyStruct<T>>
        where T : struct
    {
        private readonly T _value;

        public MyStruct(T val) { this._value = val; }

        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            return false;
        }

        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            return base.GetHashCode();
        }

        public static bool operator ==(MyStruct<T> a, MyStruct<T> b)
        {
            return false;
        }

        public static bool operator !=(MyStruct<T> a, MyStruct<T> b)
        {
            return false;
        }

        public bool Equals(MyStruct<T> other)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Expression<Func<MyStruct<int>, Nullable<MyStruct<int>>, bool>> expr = 
                (value, nullableValue) => value == nullableValue;
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

**Update**: Greatly simplified the code that reproduces the exception

---

**Also**: Note that using a Func instead of an expression does not cause this exception:

```
Func<MyStruct<int>, Nullable<MyStruct<int>>, bool> func =
    (value, nullableValue) => value == nullableValue;

func(new MyStruct<int>(), null);
```

The above runs with no errors.

---

**Update 3**: Seems that removing the `IEquatable<>` interface doesn't prevent the exception, so the code can be further simplified.

Comment: Shouldn't expression be expr = 
                (value, nullableValue) => value == nullableValue.Value;

Comment: Can you make the parameters to the expression both nullable?  If you do that I imagine it would work.

Comment: @Servy, it will work. But I'm trying to understand what that exception means. Shouldn't this cause an implicit cast?

Comment: Well that doesn't match the signature then  Expression<Func<MyStruct<int>, Nullable<MyStruct<int>>, bool>> you are saying nullablevalue is nullable type

Comment: @cheedep I'm trying to figure out why == without .Value causes an exception here. If the expression was a Func it doesn't happen (see updated question)

Comment: See Eric Lippert's comment on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/840150/linq-and-the-equality-operator-expression-of-type-system-int32-cannot-be-used. That applies perfectly to this too.

Comment: @cheedep, thanks - that's an interesting comment by Eric there. I'm not certain it applies here as we're discussing lifting value types into nullables, not inheritance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently what's happening here is related to a difference between generic structs (in this case `MyStruct<T>`) vs. non-generic structs. If I change the struct to the following simpler non-generic class, the exception disappears:

```cs
struct MyStruct
{
    private readonly int _value;

    public MyStruct(int val) { this._value = val; }

    public override bool Equals(object obj) { return false; }
    public override int GetHashCode() { return base.GetHashCode(); }

    public static bool operator ==(MyStruct a, MyStruct b) { return false; }
    public static bool operator !=(MyStruct a, MyStruct b) { return false; }
}
```

For regular (non-generic) structs, the .NET is content with creating expressions that seem to pass nullables to the op_Equality method (which does not accept nullables).

For generic structs, it fails with that strange exception.

I still don't know **why there's a difference** between generic and non-generic structs, so I'm going to ask this [in a separate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16797890/why-are-generic-and-non-generic-structs-treated-differently-when-building-expres).

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:** *I am going to leave this answer here even though the question kind of changed, but may help with future folks looking into this:*

The below corrects the issue when using `Expression<Func<..>>`, but the OP found that just using `Func<...>` solved this issue.

---

You are getting this because your `operator==` is looking for `MyStruct<T>` for both parameters, but you are trying to pass in `Nullable<MyStruct<T>>`.

You need to make an override to handle the `Nullable<MyStruct<T>>`

Comment: See my updated question - if you use just a Func (not an Expression<Func>) the same code works with no exceptions raised.

Comment: Also, I think anyway it lifts it to a Nullable, furthermore - if you remove the IEquatable interface it works.

Comment: @sinelaw Good to know. I tested my answer against your original Expression<Func<,>> in a test console app and it worked. Thanks for the information on just using Func<>

Comment: @sinelaw: `Func<>` works because the compiler is doing the heavy lifting (pun intended). With expressions, you have to do all the work, which usually involves a lot of explicit casts so that all types match perfectly. This answer is indeed correct.

Comment: @AllonGuralnek, see my answer below - none of this makes sense to me because for non-genric structs everything works just fine. I'm going to post the full details in a new question that narrows it down to the difference between generic and non-generic types.