# Why are generic and non-generic structs treated differently when building expression that lifts operator == to nullable?

Tags: c#, generics, nullable, compiler-bug

This looks like a bug in lifting to null of operands on generic structs.

Consider the following dummy struct, that overrides `operator==`:

```cs
struct MyStruct
{
    private readonly int _value;
    public MyStruct(int val) { this._value = val; }

    public override bool Equals(object obj) { return false; }
    public override int GetHashCode() { return base.GetHashCode(); }

    public static bool operator ==(MyStruct a, MyStruct b) { return false; }
    public static bool operator !=(MyStruct a, MyStruct b) { return false; }
}
```

Now consider the following expressions:

```cs
Expression<Func<MyStruct, MyStruct, bool>> exprA   = 
    (valueA, valueB) => valueA == valueB;

Expression<Func<MyStruct?, MyStruct?, bool>> exprB = 
    (nullableValueA, nullableValueB) => nullableValueA == nullableValueB;

Expression<Func<MyStruct?, MyStruct, bool>> exprC  = 
    (nullableValueA, valueB) => nullableValueA == valueB;
```

All three compile and run as expected.

When they're compiled (using `.Compile()`) they produce the following code (paraphrased to English from the IL):

1. The first expression that takes only `MyStruct` (not nullable) args, simply calls `op_Equality` (our implementation of `operator ==`)
2. The second expression, when compiled, produces code that checks each argument to see if it `HasValue`. If both don't (both equal `null`), returns `true`. If only one has a value, returns `false`. Otherwise, calls `op_Equality` on the two values.
3. The third expression checks the nullable argument to see if it has a value - if not, returns false. Otherwise, calls `op_Equality`.

So far so good.

Next step: do the exact same thing with a generic type - change `MyStruct` to `MyStruct<T>` everywhere in the definition of the type, and change it to `MyStruct<int>` in the expressions.

Now the third expression compiles but throws a runtime exception `InvalidOperationException` with the following message:

> The operands for operator 'Equal' do not match the parameters of method 'op_Equality'.

I would expect generic structs to behave exactly the same as non-generic ones, with all the nullable-lifting described above.

So my questions are:

1. Why is there a difference between generic and non-generic structs?
2. What is the meaning of this exception?
3. Is this a bug in C#/.NET?

---

The full code for reproducing this is [available on this gist](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5664417).

Comment: Could you post your modified code as well? It looks like you might have missed a spot when copy-pasting `MyStruct<int>` in place of `MyStruct`.

Comment: I've added a [gist](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5664417) with the full code, also added a link at the end of the question.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The short answer is: yes, that's a bug. I've put a minimal repro and a short analysis below.

My apologies. I wrote a lot of that code and so it was likely my bad.

I have sent a repro off to the Roslyn development, test and program management teams. I doubt this reproduces in Roslyn, but they'll verify that it does not and decide whether this makes the bar for a C# 5 service pack.

Feel free to enter an issue on connect.microsoft.com as well if you want it tracked there as well.

---

Minimal repro:

```
using System;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
struct S<T>
{
    public static bool operator ==(S<T> a, S<T> b) { return false; }
    public static bool operator !=(S<T> a, S<T> b) { return false; }
}
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Expression<Func<S<int>?, S<int>, bool>> x = (a, b) => a == b;
    }
}
```

---

The code that is generated in the minimal repro is equivalent to

```
ParameterExpression pa = Expression.Parameter(typeof(S<int>?), "a");
ParameterExpression pb = Expression.Parameter(typeof(S<int>), "b");
Expression.Lambda<Func<S<int>?, S<int>, bool>>(
    Expression.Equal(pa, pb, false, infoof(S<int>.op_Equality)
    new ParameterExpression[2] { pa, pb } );
```

Where `infoof` is a fake operator that gets a `MethodInfo` for the given method.

The correct code would be:

```
ParameterExpression pa = Expression.Parameter(typeof(S<int>?), "a");
ParameterExpression pb = Expression.Parameter(typeof(S<int>), "b");
Expression.Lambda<Func<S<int>?, S<int>, bool>>(
    Expression.Equal(pa, Expression.Convert(pb, typeof(S<int>?), false, infoof(S<int>.op_Equality)
    new ParameterExpression[2] { pa, pb } );
```

The `Equal` method cannot deal with one nullable, one non-nullable operands. It requires that either both are nullable or neither is.

(Note that the `false` is correct. This Boolean controls whether the result of a lifted equality is a lifted Boolean; in C# it is not, in VB it is.)

Comment: Once again, thanks Eric. I've opened a [bug on connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/788793/expression-equal-with-one-nullable-and-one-plain-generic-struct-value-causes-invalidoperationexception#).

Comment: Allow me to also comment that without quick responses like these, our team in the past would wait months or even years for a proper clarification on Connect, during which we implemented workarounds that may or may not be correct. I hope that someone still at Microsoft will make fast responses an official policy.

Comment: @sinelaw: You're welcome. The Roslyn team confirms to me that this does repro in C# 5 but does not repro in Roslyn by the way. See Neal's answer.

Comment: You tease with the `infoof` operator, Eric. Any hope this is a portent of good things to come in C#?

Comment: Interesting. This code also reproduces the bug: `using System;
using System.Linq.Expressions;

static class Program
{
  static ArraySegment<string> A;
  static ArraySegment<string>? B;
  static void Main()
  {
    Expression<Func<bool>> e = () => A == B;
  }
}
` By the way, it can also happen when the struct is non-generic but is nested inside a generic class.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, this bug is gone in Roslyn (the compiler under development).  We'll see about the existing product.